# Google Apps Script with forms to check if a doc url is 'shared'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Does anyone know "IF" it is possible to use Google Apps Script with a Google form to auto check "IF" a document URL pasted into the form is a "shared" document?

I'm a teacher and I use Google forms to collect student work, but one of the biggest problems I experience is that students regularly submit url's to "unshared" documents for grading. I'd like to reduce/eliminate this by the form checking the entered document url to see if it is 'shared' befor the form is submitted.

Is this possible? If yes, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is the form I'm currently using.
http://mrbenrud.com/index.php/2012-09-08-21-09-45/submit-your-work

Comment: This could be of interest for you: http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/

Comment: The link in the question is not working. I'm wondering if it pointed to a webpage with an embedded Google Form or if the referred form is of another kind.

Answer (score 1):

The answer validation in Google Forms could be done with Google Apps Script after the students submit their responses, i.e. by using [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) event.

Once the answer was submitted, you could use the [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) to get properties like:

- Viewers
- Editors
- Owner

It's worth to say that in the 2014 summer Google launched [Google Classroom](http://google.com/edu/classroom) to help teachers to manage the assignments of their classes among other tasks.

## References

[Validate answers in your form - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en)